# prevent calling member function via pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

Consider the code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo& operator*() = delete;
    Foo* operator->() = delete;
    void f()
    {
        std::cout << "Foo::f()" << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;
    // foo -> f(); // invokes deleted operator ->, so it doesn't compile

    Foo* pFoo = new Foo;    
    pFoo -> f(); // how can we make this not compilable?
    delete pFoo;
}
```

Is there any way to prevent the next to last line `pFoo -> f();` from compiling? In other words, I want to be able to create a pointer to the object, but not to be able to use it in calling member functions. Deleting `operator*()` and `operator->()` doesn't work, since they are invoked only by `Foo` and not by a pointer to `Foo`.

PS: I want to be able to create the object on the heap, so marking `operator new` as private is not an option.

Comment: that's not possible. `pFoo->f()` will always compile as long as `f()` is accessible.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  I'm sure some convoluted C++ tricks will be offered as answers but is it really going to be worth it to implement and maintain them?

Comment: @AndreyMishchenko I don't want to do this in my code, was related to a different question I saw here and was trying to figure out if it is possible (just curiosity).

Comment: @T.C. the whole idea was to have an in-between case: allow heap creation but disallow some function calls. Right now we can disable heap creation completely by deleting (making private) the `operator new`

Comment: You could accomplish this by, for example, making a class which derives from `private Foo` and passing around pointers to the parent class (supposing that you want to use the pointers as handles to objects, but don't want holders of the handles to be able to actually use the class member methods).

Comment: You're going down a dark path, @vsoftco. Stop trying to prohibit everything and accept C++ for what it is with the features that it has.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ha ha, fair enough :) Although sometimes we learn something from the dark side :) See e.g. template metaprogramming

Answer (score 7):

You cannot because you cannot change the semantics of built in types.

`operator ->` and `operator*` will always work for the built-in `Foo*`. Then, as it is shorthand for `(*pFoo).f()`, you have a valid `Foo` object on which the public `f()` can be invoked.

Comment: Well, you could use your own user-defined pointer of course if that fits your usecase.

Answer (score 0):

How about create a const pointer `const Foo* pFoo = new Foo;` and you won't be able to use non-const methods of the class.